# Change DataGridRow color according to min value

Tags: c#, wpf, list, datagrid, background-color

I have made a UI which contains a `Button` and a `DataGrid`. I have made a few calculations in the code that generate four lists which look like this:

```
var L = new List<MyDataObject>();
for (int z = 0; z < list_Exp.Count; z++)
{
    var d = new MyDataObject();

    d.AmountNeed = Math.Ceiling((goalexp - currentexp) / (list_Exp[z]));
    d.TotalLose = d.AmountNeed * (list_Amount_MadeFrom_One[z] * list_BuyPrice_MadeFrom_One[z] + list_Amount_MadeFrom_Two[z] * list_BuyPrice_MadeFrom_Two[z]);
    d.TotalGain = d.AmountNeed * list_AmountMade[z] * list_SellPrice[z];
    d.TotalCost = d.TotalGain - d.TotalLose;

    L.Add(d);
}
```

Once I got the lists I find the min value in a specific list:

```
int i = L.FindIndex(x => x.TotalCost == L.Min(y => y.TotalCost));
```

And add all the lists into `dataGrid`:

```
dataGrid.ItemsSource = L;
```

Now, I have been trying to change the color of `Rows[i]` to green or any other color. I have tried stuff like:

```
grid.Columns["NameOfColumn"].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
```

or

```
dataGrid.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[columnIndex].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

and nothing works.

Thank You.

Comment: You want the entire row to change color? Or just one cell in the row?

Comment: entire row at index [i] mate.

Comment: What type of control is dataGridView1?  Your sample code seems to be showing different controls from the dataGrid that you are setting to display your list.

Comment: i edited it mate, my bad. i tried different codes from forums. the control i have is `dataGrid` and `button`. The whole code is written inside the button class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could for example define a `RowStyle` and handle the `Loaded` event for the `DataGridRow` container something like this:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid">
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <EventSetter Event="Loaded" Handler="RowLoaded" />
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

---

```
private void RowLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridRow dgr = sender as DataGridRow;
    MyDataObject x = dgr.DataContext as MyDataObject;
    if (x.TotalCost == dataGrid.Items.OfType<MyDataObject>().Min(y => y.TotalCost))
        dgr.Background = Brushes.Green;
}
```

> only problem is when i scroll down (i have many rows), it colors few rows instead of finding only 1 min and then i get an error: "NullReferenceEXception was unhandled"

You could bind the `Background` property of the `DataGridRow` container to the current `MyDataObject` and the collection of objects and use a `MultiValueConverter` then:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <local:Converter x:Key="conv" />
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource conv}">
                        <Binding Path="." />
                        <Binding Path="ItemsSource" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

---

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class Converter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            MyDataObject x = values[0] as MyDataObject;
            if(x != null)
            {
                IEnumerable<MyDataObject> collection = values[1] as IEnumerable<MyDataObject>;
                if(collection != null && x.TotalCost == collection.Min(y => y.TotalCost))
                    return System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Green;
            }

            return System.Windows.DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried and i get  "contains state information and event data associated with a routed event"

Comment: @mm8 You forgot the variable name for the second parameter.

Comment: Thank You both =]

Comment: @mm8 only problem is when i scroll down (i have many rows), it colors few rows instead of finding only 1 min and then i get an error: "NullReferenceEXception was unhandled"

Comment: @mm8,First really thank you for helping. I added your update and im having troubles at "The name "Converter" does not exist in the namespace 'clr-namescape.... "

Comment: Sorry, it should be xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1" provided that you defined the Converter class is in the "WpfApplication1" namespace as per my example. I edited my answer.

Comment: thats what i did before also =], i heard it might be problems with local driver because it says "the type `local:Converter` was not found.verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built". Thank You again for the patience.

Comment: Did you add the converter class that I posted to your solution and build?

Comment: You were awesome mate, my bad in placing the code at right place. thanks again.